# Why do we use req.body while creating any model?

Tags: node.js, express

Following some tutorial there comes a code in which req.body is used.Is it a middleware(body-Parser)?can look at my comments where req.body is used.

```
        Review.create({
        title : req.body.title,  //here it is used!!
        description : req.body.description,
        rating: req.body.rating,
        done : false
    }, function(err, review) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
```

And if it is a third party middleware then how does it functions in the code?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/anatomy-of-an-http-transaction/, https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.body

Comment: This is why we have documentation for code. :)

Comment: @tomtom your links helps a lot thanks much

Answer (score 1):

`req` is an object containing information about the `HTTP` request that raised the event. In response to `req`, you use `res` to send back the desired `HTTP` response.
`req.body` holds parameters that are sent up from the client as part of a POST request. See the [API](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.body).